# Почему запись криво идет?

Tags: python

```
file = open("D:\python проекты\o.txt", "r+",encoding="utf-8")
txt = ""
L=file.readline()
while L!="":   
   position = 0
   txt_line = ""
   for m in L.split("+"):
      if(position == 5):
         m = str(int(m) + 1)
      txt_line += (m + "+") if position != 9  else m
      position += 1
   txt += txt_line
   L=file.readline()

file.truncate(0)
file.write(txt)
file.close()
```

Файл o.txt:

```
Слово1+перевод+дата+пример ассоциации+пример предложений+25+общий уровень усвояемости+категория+часть речи+глагол
Слово2+перевод+дата+пример ассоциации+пример предложений+25+общий уровень усвояемости+категория+часть речи+глагол
Слово3+перевод+дата+пример ассоциации+пример предложений+25+общий уровень усвояемости+категория+часть речи+глагол
Слово4+перевод+дата+пример ассоциации+пример предложений+25+общий уровень усвояемости+категория+часть речи+глагол
Слово5+перевод+дата+пример ассоциации+пример предложений+25+общий уровень усвояемости+категория+часть речи+глагол
Слово6+перевод+дата+пример ассоциации+пример предложений+25+общий уровень усвояемости+категория+часть речи+глагол
```

Здесь была попытка реализовать программу для повторения слов. Сама она не полная, но тут к столбцу 6 прибавляется единица к текущему значению. Пока что в силу плохого знания python я считую файл, копируя его в переменную с нужными изменениями. Только потом перезаписую файл. Я вывел переменную txt, и она нормально вывелась, но в файле первая строка куда-то съезжает. Помогите разобраться, почему так

Comment: *в файле первая строка куда-то съезжает* - что значит "съезжает"? С приведённым в вопросе файлом вроде всё нормально.

Comment: Потому что вы не делаете seek после truncate, например?

Comment: @wchistow проверьте наличие нулевых байтов в начале файла после записи

Comment: @andreymal СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!!!